# Get value from ComboBox?

Tags: combobox, enums, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have in **MyForm** a **ComboBox** (*myComboBox* ) with EnumType *myEnumType* .

In the  `modified` method , I want to get the value.

I used the code looklike:

```
if (myComboBox.enumTypeValue() == myEnumType::Value1 )
{
//action
}
```

Or anothe way

```
if (myComboBox.enumType(myEnumType::Value1) )
{
//action
}
```

In both cases I can not take the value.

What is the way? Thanks, all!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the value of the ComboBox use the `selection` method,

```
if(myComboBox.selection() == myEnumType::Value1) {
   //action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the code looklike:

```
public boolean modified()
{
   boolean ret;
   if(btMailTxt.valueStr()== 'FR')
   {
      btMailSubject.text('ooox');
      btMailBody.text('Bonjouro');
   }
   if(btMailTxt.valueStr()== 'NL')
   {
       btMailSubject.text('assigntest');
       btMailBody.text('Bonjour');
   }

   ret = super();
   return ret;
}
```